# Magento where is catalog product grid place

Tags: magento

Magento where is catalog product grid place in admin side of magento?

```
index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLock file path is `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php`

Controller path is `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php` index  action